# heroku build failed reason

Tags: node.js, heroku

Today morning  heroku deployment are all failing with following error

```
 node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(39,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
       node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(39,49): error TS1005: ';' expected.
       node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(39,52): error TS1109: Expression expected.
       node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(318,75): error TS1005: '>' expected.
       node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(318,100): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
       node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(318,109): error TS1005: '=' expected.
       node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(318,126): error TS1005: '(' expected.
```

My app is not using this package and I am not sure about the error.

anyone receiving the same error or know what to do?

Comment: clear the heroku.cache and try an 'empty' build -  https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

Comment: not working .. It is trying to rebuild

Comment: does it build on local machine after a 'clean' ?  on local machine , if you delete dir=node_modules then do npm install and then build ... is it OK?

Comment: Yes in local is working. As per support I might need to upgrade typescript

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: @GelSisaed I was using lodash lib and the upgraded Typescript lib version was not compatible hence I upgraded the lodash library.